# A silly problem on equivalent statements of linear dependence

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $v_1, \cdots, v_n \in V$ where $V$ a vector space. Exhibit that the following are equivalent:

(1) The vectors are linearly dependent

(2) There exist scalars $a_1, \cdots, a_n$ not all zero such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_iv_i = 0$

(3) For some $0 \le i < n$ we have $v_i \in \operatorname{span}\{v_j \ | \ 1 \le j < i\}$

(4) For some $0 \le i \le n$ we have $v_i \in \operatorname{span}\{v_j \ | \ 1 \le j \le n,\ \ i \neq j\}$

I am only left with proving that $(2) \implies (3) \implies (4)$. Any help?

Comment: In (4), $0\le i\le n$ should probably read $0\le j\le n$.

Comment: Absolutely! In (3) as well!

Comment: Shouldn't it be $0 < j$? The lowest index in your family of vectors is 1, not 0.

Comment: As well, on the left, the interval should be $0 < i \leq n$ as you number your vectors from 1-n.

Comment: @JackM Good eyes!

Comment: Also, how is "linearly dependant" defined if not with (2) or (4)?

Comment: @JackM E.g. $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ are linearly dependent if some $v_i$ is a linear combination of the other $v_j$s. Surely this is obviously equivalent to (2), but the formulation is after all a bit different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for 2 to 3: Let there are $a_1, a_2,...,a_n$ not all zero such that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_iv_i=0$. So at least we know there is an $a_k,~~1\leq k\leq n$ such that $a_k\neq 0$. W e have $a_1v_1+a_2v_2+...+a_kv_k+...a_nv_n=0$ and so $$v_k=\frac{a_1v_1+a_2v_2+...+a_{k-1}v_k+a_{k+1}v_{k+1}...a_nv_n}{-a_k}$$ This means 3 is held.

Comment: I think this is incorrect. You are only allowed to have vectors that are of lower index than $k$ which is clearly not the case here.

Comment: @Stefan: it's essentially correct. I added a comment to my answer below to finish this off.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This clarifies things!

Comment: Good observations! +1

Comment: When do you sleep, Babak? ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: 5 hours later, I will be in the Heaven!

Answer (score 2):

(3) $\Rightarrow$ (4) is trivial: write the vector $v_i$ from (3) as a linear combination of those with indices $1, \dots, i-1$ (which is what (3) says you can do), and choose $a_j = 0$ for all (if any) $j > i$.

**Edit**: *to finish the proof of (2) to (3)* of the other answer, choose $i$ such that $a_i$ is the *largest* non-zero coefficient you get from (2). Then everything goes through as in the proof.

Comment: Thanks for what you have done for clarify the main point. I usally assume some things are clear o the OP. Thanks again.

Comment: @BabakS.: NP! A little remark was all it took.